# Is it possible to create a beacon with Classic Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon

I'm attempting to use a classic bluetooth chip to possibly send out signals to another device with a classic bluetooth chip.

Now would it be possible to create a beacon with classic bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can.  A Bluetooth LE beacon typically sends out regular advertisements with a unique identifier that can be picked up by a receiving device (typically a mobile phone) doing a Bluetooth LE scan.  Since you can also send out advertisements and do scans with classic Bluetooth, you could build the same thing with this technology.

The main disadvantage is that classic Bluetooth uses much more power, both for transmitting the beacon signal and more importantly for doing the scans.  So if you are using mobile phones to detect the beacons the battery drain will be much higher than if using Bluetooth LE.

Comment: I'm not too worried about the power, it's a device with an auxiliary power supply. But I was wondering, with a beacon of classic bluetooth, do the devices need to communicate back and forth? Or can it just broadcast one way?

Comment: When you scan for classic Bluetooth devices on your computer, the  Bluetooth chip it is looking for advertising devices that have been made "discoverable".  You can use this same technique to look for classic Bluetooth beacons which are always discoverable.  You do not need to pair in this use case.