# what is interval time of advertising classic Bluetooth in discoverable mode

Tags: android, bluetooth

From this quesiton [is-it-possible-to-create-a-beacon-with-classic-bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786700/is-it-possible-to-create-a-beacon-with-classic-bluetooth)

I see it is possible to simulate a beacon using discoverable mode.
So is disciverable mode an advertising action? and if yes, what is the advertising interval time? And how to sniff these advertising packets?